# The membership function of Consequents (Outputs) in Fuzzy classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, fuzzy-logic

The
problem in *Iris data* is to classify three species of iris (*setosa, versicolor and virginica*) by
four-dimensional attribute vectors consisting of

- sepal length (x1)
- sepal width (x2)
- petal length (x3)
- petal width (x4)

Every attribute of the fuzzy classifier is assigned with three linguistic
terms (fuzzy sets): short, medium and long. With normalized attribute values the
membership functions of these fuzzy sets for all the four attributes are depicted in the
figure below:

[image: Membership Function]

Now, consider the situation that a set of Rules are given - some examples are as below:

- R1: If (x3=short OR medium) AND (x4=short) Then iris **setosa**
- R2: If (x2=short OR medium) AND (x3=long) AND (x4=long) Then iris **virginica**

Now, I want to make a fuzzy classifier on Iris dataset. The problem here is, I need to use a membership function for Consequents in Rules(i.e, The 3 classes) so as to be able to compute aggregation of rules and difuzzification.

- What is the proper pre-defined domain and membership function for three classes?
- All the Consequents (Outputs)  in fuzzy classifier need to acquire membership functions?